# Selecting a name tag of kml features from within QGIS

Tags: kml, google-earth, qgis

Starting from a .csv file I created a kml file using QGIS (2.8 Wien). The .csv file has 5 columns in the following order: Latitude, Longitude, Name, parameter and temporal acquisition.
When I create the .kml file, it puts the place-mark in the correct position, but instead of seeing names I see numbers. These numbers correspond to the "Feature Id" showed when clicking on "Identify feature" button.

Is there a way to change these numbers into another values, possibly using the "name" column directly, in order to see the name and not a number on Google Earth?

Answer (score 0):

This question should stay in gis.stackexchange.com

Anyway you can easily configure kml feature label filling the appropriate field in the export window:
[image]